# How to add a class to delimiter using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, delimiter, number-with-delimiter

I have added a comma to a large number using the number_with_delimiter call, now I'd like to add a class to the comma.

This is my code to get the commas

```
= "#{number_with_delimiter(1000, delimiter: ",")}"
```

I think the code to add the class to the commas should look something like this but its not working.

```
= "#{number_with_delimiter(1000, delimiter: ",", class:"hello")}"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess `class` is not one of the available options for `number_with_delimiter`.

Comment: what do you mean by `add a class to the comma`? Do you want the comma to be wrapped in a HTML element (like a span) having the HTML class 'hello' ?

Comment: I am trying to add the class specifically to the comma so I can style it differently than the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping each comma in a span tag and add a class to that span.  Example:

```
<%= number_with_delimiter(1000, delimiter: "<span class='hello'>,</span>".html_safe) %>
```

Comment: This is what the output is when I do that:

1&lt;span class='hello'&gt;,&lt;/span&gt;000

Comment: Are you sure you have `html_safe` on the end of the method call? You could also do this: `<%= raw number_with_delimiter(1000, delimiter: "<span class='hello'>,</span>") %>`

Comment: This is the output now: [1<span class='hello'>,</span>000]

Comment: Oops, sorry, I put `html_safe` in the wrong place (it should instead be on the delimiter string).  I've edited the answer; please try again.

Comment: It still output '1<span class='hello'>,</span>000'

Comment: I just tried using the jquery '.filter()' function and was able to find a solution

Comment: The approach definitely works, I just tested it and confirmed that the browser renders it appropriately. Glad you found a solution, but using jQuery for this kind of problem is overkill.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!